# reloadData is not working in didUpdateToLocation method

Tags: ios, localization, delegates, tableview

I have a huge problem woth refeshing and reloading data in tableView in my app. Application is going to be a simple tracking/sport app that is using gps. It is tabbed application I have a few ViewController classes and AppDelegate class. In App delegate class i have locationManager and implemented didUpdateToLocation method for him .

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {


NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lat. %f degrees", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Long. %f degrees",
                       newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
NSString *altitude =
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Alt. %f m", newLocation.altitude];
NSString *speed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Speed %f m/s", newLocation.speed]; NSString *course =
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Course %f degrees", newLocation.course];

[self.rows insertObject:latitude atIndex:0];
[self.rows insertObject:longitude atIndex:1];
[self.rows insertObject:altitude atIndex:2];
[self.rows insertObject:speed atIndex:3];
[self.rows insertObject:course atIndex:4];
[self.fourthViewContorller.tableView reloadData];
 NSLog(@"Location: %@", [newLocation description]);}
```

As you can see ath the end i try to reload data using ReloadData message. Well it doesn't work. 
fourthViewContorller is a pointer to ViewController class where tabelView is. Declaration in AppDelegate.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AppFourthViewController * fourthViewContorller;
```

At the same time in AppFourthViewController.m this method works and refresh data

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Im newbie in iOS development and im not sure that i do everything right. Mabye i should somehow connect this pointer in AppDelegate.h with view in storyboard? It seems that this pointer is not leading to proper view because new data keep coming at console, and data at tabe only change when i switch tab.

Here are some important methods in AppFourtViewController:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tv 
{
    return 1; 
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tv numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section 
{
    return 5; 
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"cell"; UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"]; 

    if ( cell == nil ) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone; 
    }

    AppAppDelegate *delegate = (AppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    cell.textLabel.text = [delegate.rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell; 
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling [super viewDidAppear:animated] in viewWillAppear method?

Comment: i was trying something, deleting it changes nothing.I'm not sure how i can communicate from delegate to view. Other way worked with [UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] and i can't figure out how to make delegate referesh table in one of tabs

Comment: When you are saying,it is now working, what does it mean? Is Table data is not visible or is it not refreshing?

Comment: It is not refreshing. It is refreshing when i switch tab and than go back to tab with table, so viewWillAppear fire proprely. reloadData in AppDelegate also run, but table is not refreshed. Everything else work fine

Comment: can you show me where and how did you declare tableView?

Comment: it is in header of AppFourthViewController `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppFourthViewController :     UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;


@end`

Comment: can you use breakpointer in this statement [self.fourthViewContorller.tableView reloadData] and check if tableview is nil or not?

Comment: i have checked it and yes it is nil

Answer (score 0):

TableView's property attribute is weakly defined, change it to strong as follows

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView
```

It should work!!!

Comment: unfortunately it's not working :( tableView is still nil, and screen on the simulator doesn't update values

Comment: can you check if self.fourthViewContorller contains nil or not?

Comment: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s39/sh/49e8740f-9fbb-4e4b-9ffc-dc63f2699694/1696b0f8f35d8e6ef26d422d198e81d1 this is what i see after setting a breakpoint at [self.fourthViewContorller.tableView reloadData]

Comment: And it shows your fourthViewController as nil as well which might be the problem.

Comment: where and how did you initialised fourthViewController in your app delegate?

Comment: hmm...there is the thing that i didn't i have only declare it...i just tried `self.fourthViewContorller = [[AppFourthViewController alloc] init];` in  AppAppDelegate.m in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method but with no results...fourthViewContorller is not nil but now is just some new object not my view.

Comment: No, it will work in that way. You have to initialise it with the same FourViewController that will be shown to the user.

Comment: `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    
    if ( [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] ) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 15;
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    self.rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
    //self.fourthViewContorller = [[AplikacjaTreningowaFourthViewController alloc] init];` first part

Comment: `[self.rows insertObject:@"Lat." atIndex:0];
    [self.rows insertObject:@"Long." atIndex:1];
    [self.rows insertObject:@"Alt." atIndex:2];
    [self.rows insertObject:@"Speed" atIndex:3];
    [self.rows insertObject:@"Course" atIndex:4];
    
            return YES;
}` second

Comment: hmmm...i'm not sure i understand question. I created view and table view in storyboard and it suppose to just work with code i provided.

Comment: nwm i just used NSNotificationCenter. Still curious why this doesn't work - it is example from book, and here on SO people also are saying taht i suppose to be able to communicate from delegate to view that way. Wall i only lost one day on this :)